# Inserting node at head in a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, insert, head

So I've been trying to write a code of various operations on 2 linked lists using functions and while the lists are being created properly and insertion and deletion is taking place correctly at all positions but inserting at the head condition seems to be not working.

I tried creating an LL using this function:

```
void Create(struct node **head) {
    if (No_of_List==2)
    {
        cout<<"\nCan't create more lists\n";
        Operations();
    }
    int n;
    cout<<"Create a linked list.\n\nEnter the number of elements in the Linked List: ";
    cin>>n;
    if (n!=0)
    {
        No_of_List++;
    }
    LIST_SIZE=n;
    while(n--)
    {
        cout<<"Enter the value to be inserted: ";
        node *new_node= new node;
        cin>>new_node->data;
        new_node->next=0;

        if(Empty_List(*head)==1)
            *head=new_node;
        else
        {
            temp=*head;
            while (temp->next!=NULL)
                temp=temp->next;
            temp->next=new_node;
        }
    }
    Operations();
}
```

and my insertion code is:

```
node *new_node = new node;
cout<<"Enter the value to be inserted: ";
cin>>new_node->data;
new_node->next=NULL;
int index;
cout<<"Enter the index: ";
cin>>index;
        
if (index==0)                               // CONDITION NOT WORKING
{
    new_node->next=head;
    head=new_node;
    cout<<"Value inserted successfully.\n";
    LIST_SIZE++;
    goto l;
    return;
}
        
if (index>LIST_SIZE)
{
    cout<<"Invalid index.";
    goto l;
    return;
}
        
temp=head;
temp1=NULL;
if (Empty_List(head)==1)
{
    cout<<"\nLinked List empty.\n";
}
    
for (int i=0;i<index;i++)
{
    temp1=temp;
    temp=temp->next;
}
temp1->next=new_node;
new_node->next=temp;
cout<<"Value inserted successfully.\n";
LIST_SIZE++;
}
```

but my index=0 condition doesnt insert any value at the head whereas the other value is inserted at other index places. Pls help

**Note: ** *this is a code snippet only. you can ask for the full code to find any other errors but it's a long one so I didnt insert it here*
https://onlinegdb.com/r1UzIfzPD Here's the full code

Comment: Start stripping/refactoring and prune this down to a [mcve] (stress the **minimal** part). We should be able to take what you posted (and *only* what you posted), copy/paste it, compile+link+run it with requisite input data (that you also provide), and reproduce your misfortunate error.

Comment: `if (index==0) // CONDITION NOT WORKING` ...even if you input `0`? That's hard to believe. Btw. and O.T.: `goto l; return;` I don't like the `goto l;` but the following `return;` seems definitely to be unreachable.

Comment: can't understand why you are using goto and where you sending pointer because I could not see ```l``` is pointing. If you want I can provide you better whole new solution.

Comment: The main code has been added for reference too. I hope it makes it easier to understand. Thanks @AnkitMishra

Comment: @Scheff just realised the return is of no use but yeah the code doesn't work. The full code has been uploaded for reference if the issue can be found. Thank you